# A simple lock-free queue for work stealing

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, queue, lock-free

I am currently reading the book *C++ Concurrency in Action* by Anthony Williams. In chapter 9, he implemented a lock-based work stealing queue and mentioned it is possible to implement a lock-free queue that allows the owner thread to push and pop at one end while other threads can steal entries from the other. So, I implemented it myself here. Basically, I have 3 methods: `push`, `try_pop_back`, and `try_steal_front`.

1. `push` will always add a new item to the *back* of the queue
2. `try_pop_back` tries to pop an existing item from the *back* of the queue
3. `try_steal_front` tries to steal from the *front* of the queue

This queue is thread local, and `push`, `try_pop_back` will always be accessed by single thread, however, `try_steal_front` runs in multiple threads and will compete with `push` and `try_pop_back`. I wonder whether the code works good across all CPU architectures (e.g. Intel x86-64, AMD, ARM, etc.)

The code is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/LingyanYin/lockfree_work_stealing_queue). I have a simple test case there which could run this queue under multiple threads.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <array>

//#include "functionwrapper.h"

// push and pop are accessed by only one single thread
// thread local queue
// push/pop by this single thread could compelete with steal with multiple other threads
class LockFreeWorkStealingQueue {
private:
    // using DataType = FunctionWrapper;
    using DataType = int;
    // change to be template argument in the future
    static constexpr auto DEFAULT_COUNT = 2048u;
    static constexpr auto MASK = DEFAULT_COUNT - 1u;
    std::array<DataType, DEFAULT_COUNT> q;
    std::atomic<unsigned int> lock_front{0};
    std::atomic<unsigned int> lock_back{0};
public:
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue() {}
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue(const LockFreeWorkStealingQueue&) = delete;
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue& operator=(const LockFreeWorkStealingQueue&) = delete;

    /**
     * always add a new item to the back of the queue
     * runs sequentially with try_pop_back
     * runs parallel with multiple threads' try_steal_front
     */
    void push(DataType data) {
        auto bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        // try resetting the lock_front and lock_back to prevent
        // they being too large
        if (bk == lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
            lock_front.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
            lock_back.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
        }
        q[bk & MASK] = std::move(data);
        lock_back.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    /**
     * tries to pop an existing item from the back of the queue 
     * runs sequentially with push
     * runs parallel with multiple threads's try_steal_front
     */
    bool try_pop_back(DataType& res) {
        auto ft = lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        auto bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if (bk > ft) {
            while(bk && !lock_back.compare_exchange_weak(bk, bk - 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
            res = std::move(q[(bk - 1) & MASK]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * tries to steal from the front of the queue
     * runs in multiple threads
     */
    bool try_steal_front(DataType& res) {
        auto ft = lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        auto bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        // if there is only one item in the queue, try not steal
        // if stealing, contention with try_pop_back, failed anyway
        if (bk && ft < bk - 1) {
            while(!lock_front.compare_exchange_weak(ft, ft + 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
            // check again to see any changes by push or try_pop_back
            if (ft < lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
                res = std::move(q[ft & MASK]);
                return true;
            } else {
                // nothing to steal, reset lock_front
                lock_front.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I also add the github link and there is a simple test that runs this queue under multiple threads.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the comments. I commented out the FunctionWrapper, and I make DataType as int. @Toby Speight but you can also find the definition in the github link I just provided in the description.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not qualified to talk about memory orders, so I'll skip that part (except to note that I've never met anyone else who is, either, which is why I recommend going `seq_cst` all the way). I'll just pretend all your orders are `seq_cst`.

---

If I understand correctly, you have one "producer" thread and N "consumer" threads. The producer *pushes* items onto the *back* of the queue. The consumers *steal* items from the *front* of the queue. The producer also has one additional operation: he can *pop* items from the *back* of the queue.

I feel like your names could use some reshuffling. I would intuitively expect that the producer "owns" the back of the queue and the consumers "own" the front of the queue; this means that the name "steal" is wrong, because the consumers are merely popping off items that they are perfectly entitled to pop. (Compare `std::queue::pop_front`.)

Meanwhile, the producer owns the back of the queue, so he's not "stealing" anything; but he's not "popping" either, not from the back of a queue! (If you're pushing and popping from the same end, it's not a queue but a *stack*, and it's not the back but the *top*.) I'd say that the producer's special operation is to *take back* an item that he'd just put on the queue a moment ago.

Putting it all together, I'd call the operations:

- `push` -> `push_back`
- `try_pop_back` ->  `try_take_back`
- `try_steal_front` -> `try_pop_front`

---

Your `push` operation is not named `try_push`, implying that it cannot fail. But the function's block comment doesn't explain what you expect to happen if the queue is full! Is it supposed to overwrite, ring-buffer-style? or just "undefined behavior"? I assume "undefined behavior", but the comment should explain.

---

The `try_steal_front` (a.k.a. `try_pop_front`) function looks like the most interesting one, multithreading-wise, so I'll dig into it.

```
bool try_steal_front(DataType& res) {
    auto ft = lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    auto bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    // if there is only one item in the queue, try not steal
    // if stealing, contention with try_pop_back, failed anyway
    if (bk && ft < bk - 1) {
        while(!lock_front.compare_exchange_weak(ft, ft + 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
```

Isn't this `cmpxchg` loop just a verbose way of saying `ft = lock_front++`? (Or I suppose `ft = lock_front.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release)`?)

```
        // check again to see any changes by push or try_pop_back
        if (ft < lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
```

This line scares me because it has an atomic operation on the same line with a bunch of other computation. I strongly recommend isolating atomic operations on their own lines, even when you think it's safe (as I think it is in this case).

Let me just rewrite it in my own inefficient style:

```
bool try_pop_front(DataType& res) {
    unsigned ft = lock_front.load();
    unsigned bk = lock_back.load();
    if (bk && ft < bk - 1) {
        ft = lock_front++;
        bk = lock_back.load();
        if (ft < bk) {
            res = std::move(q[ft & MASK]);
            return true;
        } else {
            // nothing to steal, reset lock_front
            --lock_front;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Manipulating `lock_front` even in the case that there's *nothing* to steal strikes me as probably dangerous... but I'm too lazy to find out for sure. I'd definitely recommend digging into that, though.

---

But I think I found my obligatory lock-free bug anyway! Look here in `push`:

```
    // try resetting the lock_front and lock_back to prevent
    // they being too large
    if (bk == lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        lock_front.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
        lock_back.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }
```

If I understand correctly, this code is run by the *producer* thread. Elsewhere in the program, you still have a bunch of *consumer* threads which are eagerly watching the front of the queue, ready to pull items off of it as soon as `lock_front < lock_back`.

And what does the producer do here? It sets `lock_front` to `0` while `lock_back` is still very large!  There's a brief instant where, to the consumers, it looks like Christmas: suddenly the queue is *so full of items*. And they'll begin pulling off those items... until the producer finally runs the next line and sets `lock_back` to `0` (which will now be *less than* `lock_front`).

You can patch this particular bug by just switching the order of these two lines: set `lock_back` to `0` first. This fixes the immediate bug because the consumers are checking `(bk && ...)` before they pull anything off.

However, I'm fairly confident that this just makes the bug *more subtle*. Now you need two consumers in order to see the bug. Both consumers check `(bk && ...)` successfully. Then the first consumer pops an item, making the queue empty. Then the producer runs `push` (up through the resetting of `lock_back` but not `lock_front`). Now the second consumer runs:

```
if (ft < lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
```

`lock_back` is `0` and `ft` is very large, so the second consumer skips to the "failure" branch. Now the producer finishes resetting `lock_front` to `0`. And finally, the second consumer fails:

```
// nothing to steal, reset lock_front
lock_front.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);
```

So at the end of this cycle, we've got `lock_back==0, lock_front==UINT_MAX`.

*Now* a third consumer comes in, and gets an early Christmas — er, wait, no, a famine! `lock_back < lock_front` means the queue's size is "negative," right?

The producer thread is still suspended right before this line—

```
q[bk & MASK] = std::move(data);
lock_back.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
```

—and has no idea that all this is taking place.

I *think* this story holds together. Not 100% sure, though. You can never be 100% sure with lock-free code. :)

---

Corroborating evidence: Remember how I said that manipulating `lock_front` seemed dangerous? That's exactly where we found our bug! The real red flag is related to my naming discussion. Remember that the producer owns the back of the queue; the consumers own the front of the queue. The *one place* we hit our data race is *precisely* when the producer tried to modify `lock_front` — because *the producer does not own the front of the queue!*

Comment: Sharp-eyed! And also the follow-up analysis regarding * fairly confident that this just makes the bug more subtle*! I agree with you. When I worked on the code, I also suspected the resetting part in the push function, I guess I need to delete them for now, maybe find another better way to add it in. I just assume the queue is so large, then lock_front/lock_back will never lead to unsigned int overflow.

Comment: (Continued above) I guess I also need to change some names, lol. I'll keep the stealing name since it reflects this is a work stealing queue, not a general queue. But I totally agree your point if it's intended to be a general single-producer/multi-consumer queue. Many thanks! I will change my code in the next answer to reflect your comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Commented out and change the code to reflect on Quuxplusone's comments. And many thanks to Quuxplusone :)

EDIT: add comments to explain undefined behaviors in push_back.

EDIT: Change fetch_add/sub to be acq rel in the stealing mode.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <array>

#include "functionwrapper.h"

// push and pop are accessed by only one single thread
// thread local queue
// push/pop by this single thread could compelete with steal with multiple other threads
class LockFreeWorkStealingQueue {
private:
    using DataType = FunctionWrapper;
    // change to be template argument in the future
    static constexpr auto DEFAULT_COUNT = 2048u;
    static constexpr auto MASK = DEFAULT_COUNT - 1u;
    std::array<DataType, DEFAULT_COUNT> q;
    std::atomic<unsigned int> lock_front{0};
    std::atomic<unsigned int> lock_back{0};
public:
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue() {}
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue(const LockFreeWorkStealingQueue&) = delete;
    LockFreeWorkStealingQueue& operator=(const LockFreeWorkStealingQueue&) = delete;

    /**
     * add a new item to the back of the queue
     * runs sequentially with try_pop_back
     * runs parallel with multiple threads' try_steal_front
     *
     * NOTE: If this makes the queue's size 2048 or more, the behavior is undefined or
     * the contents are overwritten which will never get popped or stolen. 
     * If this is the 2^32th call to push, the behavior is undefined.
     */
    void push_back(DataType data) {
        auto bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        // try resetting the lock_front and lock_back to prevent
        // they being too large - commented out since it causes race conditions
        //if (bk == lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        //    lock_front.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
        //    lock_back.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
        //}
        q[bk & MASK] = std::move(data);
        lock_back.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    /**
     * tries to pop an existing item from the back of the queue 
     * runs sequentially with push
     * runs parallel with multiple threads's try_steal_front
     */
    bool try_pop_back(DataType& res) {
        auto ft = lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        auto bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if (bk > ft) {
            while(bk && !lock_back.compare_exchange_weak(bk, bk - 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
            res = std::move(q[(bk - 1) & MASK]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * tries to steal from the front of the queue
     * runs in multiple threads
     */
    bool try_steal_front(DataType& res) {
        auto ft = lock_front.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        auto bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        // if there is only one item in the queue, try not steal
        // if stealing, contention with try_pop_back, failed anyway
        if (bk && ft < bk - 1) {
            // while(!lock_front.compare_exchange_weak(ft, ft + 1, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
            ft = lock_front.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
            // check again to see any changes by push or try_pop_back
            bk = lock_back.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
            if (ft < bk) {
                res = std::move(q[ft & MASK]);
                return true;
            } else {
                // nothing to steal, reset lock_front
                lock_front.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: You haven't yet addressed my "block comment" comment. "Always add a new item to the back of the queue" should be more like (I think) "Add a new item to the back of the queue. If this makes the queue's size 2048 or more, the behavior is undefined. If this is the 2^32th call to `push`, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I missed that. Thanks @Quuxplusone Just added. I guess this version should be correct if we do not consider the undefined behaviors in push_back and memory_order issues. I will work on verifying the memory order stuff and also trying to eliminate the undefined behaviors if possible. Thanks again :)

Comment: "I guess this version should be correct" — I didn't say that! ;)  I'd still bet money there's a bug in it, because there's *always* a bug in lock-free code. But having grabbed the low-hanging fruit already, I'm quitting this question while I'm ahead. :)